# How to save a image filecontent into the SQL database using eloquent?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, php-5.3, eloquent

I'm getting confused about how to save an image content inside of a database table.

Please see the fourth line of code. I'm sure that this restful method (using POST) is working because `getSize()` returns the true value.

Also, if I debug what returns the 5th line I get something like the next one:

[image]

So, I'm not sure if what am I missing to save this data into the database.

```
        $personId = Input::get('PersonId');
        $file = Input::file('media');
        $tmppath = $file->getRealPath();
        $content = file_get_contents($tmppath); //$file->getSize();

        // return $content;

        $model = Person::find($personId);
        $model->Photo = $content;
        $model->save();

        $result = array(
            "success" => true,
            "data" => $personId,
            "error" => ""
        );
```

Comment: Pure curiosity, why not save the location of the image instead of the image data?

Comment: You should NOT store binary image data into a database ... store the path/filename of the image in the database like Hydra IO suggested.

Comment: Well, I was thinking in that way you're pointing out me! Do you think is more convenience save it into the server and save the filename instead of save the stream content?

Comment: Alright, could you show a code about how to save the file in a certain folder of the server? I'm new in this PHP world

Comment: Here is a really good example: http://www.tizag.com/phpT/fileupload.php

Answer (score 0):

You need to save the file to the server and only store the path in the database.

Write an appropriate method, ideally you can store it in a [trait](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php).

```
private function saveFileToDisk($file, $fileName)
{
    $path = public_path() . '/uploads/';

    return $file->move($path, $fileName . $file->getClientOriginalExtension());
}
```

An then pass the file input to your method and provide a name for the file:

```
$model->Photo = $this->saveFileToDisk(Input::file('media'), $model->Name);
```

Obvisouly you need to validate you input before all this.